# How to keep 2 or more different alternative transform?

Tags: actions

I have an object (just static object , no animation) and i want to keep 3 different alternative positions. So later, i can choose which one to use and restore it. How can i do this ?

Comment: hide and unhide?

Comment: No , i want a single object to keep 3 different take or option. like position version 1 , version 2 and version 3. So i can play and test , which position is the best option.

Comment: Have you tried shapekeys ?

Comment: @Gorgious the concept is similar, but i don't want to modify at edit level. I want to record the move/position in object mode. So in this case i want to record 3 different position. I think shape key record the modification in edit mode.

Comment: give it 3 Copy Transforms constraints with 3 different empties as target and use their visibility to switch from one to another? Or 3 keyframes and you scroll on your timeline to switch from one to another

Comment: Or 2 or more collections with different offset on each (but works only for locations).

Comment: or three actions and stash in the NLA  Is a single keyframe constant extrapolation action an animation?..  Assign the pose action in action editor to switch between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it has already been done, but that may have a general interested, so:

[image]

This is only for object location (not rotation or other) but is a base if you need something else.

Nothing particular to say about the code. Just a UI List with some associated operators (essentially done based on the templates)... and I'm far from a Blender UI specialist...

If details are needed, please ask in comments.

[image]

As asked in comments:

```
import bpy 
from bpy.props import StringProperty, FloatVectorProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty, CollectionProperty 
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, UIList, Operator, Panel 
from mathutils import Vector

def keep_locations_index_changed(self, context):
    object = context.object
    index = object.keep_locations_index
    locations = object.keep_locations
    if object and index >= 0 and locations and object.keep_locations_auto:
        if index >= len(locations):
            index = len(locations) - 1
        object.location = locations[index].location

class KeepLocations(PropertyGroup): 
    name: StringProperty( name="Name", description="Name", default="Untitled") 
    location: FloatVectorProperty( name="Location", description="", update=keep_locations_index_changed, default=Vector()) 

class MY_UL_KEEPLOCATIONS(UIList): 
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        custom_icon = 'OBJECT_DATAMODE'
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}: 
            layout.label(text=item.name, icon = custom_icon) 
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}: 
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER' 
            layout.label(text="", icon = custom_icon) 

class LIST_OT_NewItem(Operator): 
    """ Add a location to the list
    """
    bl_idname = "keep_locations.new_item" 
    bl_label = "Add a new location" 

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context): 
        return context.object 

    def execute(self, context): 
        obj_location = context.object.location
        locations = context.object.keep_locations
        index = len(locations)
        locations.add()
        locations[index].location = obj_location 
        context.object.keep_locations_index = index
        return{'FINISHED'} 
    
class LIST_OT_DeleteItem(Operator): 
    """ Remove a location from the list
    """
    bl_idname = "keep_locations.delete_item" 
    bl_label = "Deletes a location" 

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context): 
        return context.object and context.object.keep_locations
    
    def execute(self, context): 
        list = context.object.keep_locations 
        index = context.object.keep_locations_index
        list.remove(index) 
        context.object.keep_locations_index = min(max(0, index - 1), len(list) - 1) 
        return{'FINISHED'} 

class LIST_OT_GetLocation(Operator):
    """ Get the object current location and assign it to the selection
    """
    bl_idname = "keep_locations.get_location" 
    bl_label = "Gets a location" 

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context): 
        return context.object and context.object.keep_locations
    
    def execute(self, context): 
        list = context.object.keep_locations
        index = context.object.keep_locations_index
        list[index].location = context.object.location
        return{'FINISHED'} 

class LIST_OT_SetLocation(Operator):
    """ Set the select location as location of the object
    """
    bl_idname = "keep_locations.set_location" 
    bl_label = "Sets a location" 

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context): 
        return context.object and context.object.keep_locations
    
    def execute(self, context): 
        list = context.object.keep_locations
        index = context.object.keep_locations_index
        context.object.location = list[index].location
        return{'FINISHED'} 
    

class KeepLocationsPanel(Panel): 
    bl_label = "Keep locations" 
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_KEEP_LOCATIONS" 
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES' 
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW' 
    bl_context = "object" 
    
    def draw(self, context): 
        layout = self.layout 
        object = context.object 
        row = layout.row() 
        row.template_list("MY_UL_KEEPLOCATIONS", "Transforms", object, "keep_locations", object, "keep_locations_index") 
        row = layout.row() 
        row.operator(LIST_OT_NewItem.bl_idname, text='New') 
        row.operator(LIST_OT_DeleteItem.bl_idname, text='Remove') 
        
        if object.keep_locations_index >= 0 and object.keep_locations:
            row = layout.row() 
            row.prop(object, "keep_locations_auto")            
            item = object.keep_locations[object.keep_locations_index] 
            layout.row().prop(item, "name")
            layout.row().prop(item, "location") 
            row = layout.row() 
            row.operator(LIST_OT_GetLocation.bl_idname, text='Get') 
            row.operator(LIST_OT_SetLocation.bl_idname, text='Set') 

def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_class(KeepLocations) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_UL_KEEPLOCATIONS) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(LIST_OT_NewItem) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(LIST_OT_DeleteItem) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(LIST_OT_GetLocation) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(LIST_OT_SetLocation) 
    bpy.utils.register_class(KeepLocationsPanel) 
    bpy.types.Object.keep_locations_auto = BoolProperty(name = "Auto update", description="Update the object location as soon as selected", default = False) 
    bpy.types.Object.keep_locations_index = IntProperty(name = "Location", update=keep_locations_index_changed, default = 0) 
    bpy.types.Object.keep_locations = CollectionProperty(type = KeepLocations) 

def unregister(): 
    del bpy.types.Object.keep_locations_auto
    del bpy.types.Object.keep_locations 
    del bpy.types.Object.keep_locations_index
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KeepLocations) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_UL_KEEPLOCATIONS) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(KeepLocationsPanel) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LIST_OT_NewItem) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LIST_OT_DeleteItem) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LIST_OT_GetLocation) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LIST_OT_SetLocation) 
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    register()
```

Comment: This is perfect , Thanks. It's a bit error when try to remove it (2.91).

Comment: Should be correct in this last edit... tell me

Comment: And an edit again: now when "new" the new one is selected and takes the current location of the object

Comment: Could I be so bold as to request that if the answer relies on a script, please post the script (or link to it)  in your answer  rather than filling blend-exchange

Comment: @batFINGER done (and the opportunity to see another bug... will upload again...)

Comment: @lemon the previous one (has that removal error)  is fixed. Let me know if you post the latest script update. Thanks

Comment: @andio, yes just now